# How can I use list comprehension for manipulating array data by index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a piece of code that basically moves each element in a list down by 1 to make room for a new input data later on in the first position as follows:

```
wave_amp.reverse()

for i in range(len(wave_amp)-1):
    wave_amp[i] = wave_amp[i+1]enter code here

wave_amp.reverse()
```

How can I perform ths faster using list comprehension, if possible?

Comment: List comprehensions aren't for doing things faster. List comprehensions are convenient, readable ways to perform *mapping/filtering* operations on iterables to produce a *new list*. So, not sure how you'd want to use a list comprehension here (sanely). Likely, as others have pointed out, you just want `.insert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
wave_amp.insert( 0 , new_item )
```

The `list.insert(index , item)` method inserts item in desired index of list. In your case we wanna add the new item in the beginning of list, so we must insert in `index = 0`.

Or if you wanna make some room and add that item later , you can try this :

```
# Make some room in list
wave_amp = [None] + wave_amp
# ...
# Some code
# ...
wave_amp[0] = new_data
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [list.insert](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.insert(i, x)
>
> Insert an item at a given position. The first
> argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
> a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a),
> x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_input = 100
my_list.insert(0, new_input)

print(my_list)
```

output:

```
[100, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or you could insert a default value until you want to fill with the new input

```
my_list.insert(0, None)
```